# How to access Global.asax static members?

Tags: asp.net, static, global-asax

If we declare a `static` variable in `Global.asax` then how to access it inside an `ASP.NET` page ?

```
<script runat=server">

   public static object myObject = new MyClass();

   // Application_Start() and other stuff goes here.

</script>
```

And, is this a good idea for storing a global object (same instance for all requests) ?

Comment: Good question, assuming you always re-initialize the object in Application_Start().

Comment: `static` variable cannot be found although `asp.net` allows declaration. If we know coding inside `Global.asax` maps to which class then we can access that variable.

Comment: It kind of sounds like you're going about this completely backwards, Xaqron.  Maybe if you post a "bigger picture" question you'll get a more satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be better to create your object as a singleton rather than putting it as a "global" object. Instantiate it in application start, and destroy it in application end. As long as you don't need it to be across web farms, you're pretty safe.

See this post and its comments.

http://weblogs.asp.net/jeff/archive/2007/09/21/how-do-you-get-a-true-singleton-in-an-asp-net-app.aspx

Answer (score 4):

myObject should be available to all the methods in global.asax and inside your ASP.NET pages using

```
Global.myObject
```

Comment: I'm gonna use it inside a `HttpHandler` so I have access to `HttpContext` but it's not there.

Comment: you can do it but just a little differently for handlers. see this answer http://bit.ly/eT4E71

Comment: @philip: Please do not use URL shorteners on stackoverflow.  Either use the full url or use `[Url Title](http://www.example.com/address)`.

Comment: I am fine doing so but where is this rule in the [http://stackoverflow.com/faq FAQ]s?  I checked META and there are discussions about it but no decision to ban them.

Comment: @philip: That's what I'm doing right now. The problem is there are more than one `Application` instance per each `ASP.NET` application!

Comment: @philip: there's no such a `Global` object. Did you add it manually ?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would strongly vote against using global variables in ASP.NET. I had rather bad experiences some years back.

You should synchronize access to the members of your global `MyClass` instance to ensure it works correctly in a multi-threading scenario (which is likely/mandatory if multiple requests come in).

There is also the `ApplicationState` which you could use, [according to Microsoft, you shouldn't](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/694553-application-collection-page-cache-thread-safe#post2762825).

Answer (score 0):

Global is not defined
that works for me:

ASP.global_asax
example

ASP.global_asax.DefaultModel.GetTable("Tags");